# Odoo 12: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I have created a ***choice_student*** method in which I return an ID in the default of a many2one field related to res.users but I get the error :

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

This is my code :

```
student_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Etudiant', readonly=True, required=True, default=lambda self: self.choice_student()  )

@api.onchange('projet_terminer_id')
def choice_student(self):
    return self.env['res.users'].sudo().search([ ('id','=', 45)]).id
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace 'onchange' decorator with 'model'

Also field declaration.

Try with following code.

```
student_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Etudiant', readonly=True, 
                             required=True, default=_default_choice_student)

@api.model
def _default_choice_student(self):
    return self.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('id','=', 45)]).id
```

Answer (score 3):

To explain why are you getting this error, let's start step by step:

1- for default value use decorator `api.model`, and if you have the id don't use search use browse `self.env['some.model'].browse(id)`, but in you case you don't need this at all just do this:

```
    student_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Etudiant', 
                                readonly=True, required=True, 
                                default=45 )
```

2- `onchange` are also a way of setting default value **but only on the view**, because they are the first thing to be triggered by the client side after loading default values, onchange method are expected to return either `None` or a `dictionary` and this is why you are getting and error, `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'` because the returned value is not `None` so odoo is trying to get some expected values from the dictionary (like: `domain`, `values`) but oops you returned an int not a dictionary and this why Odoo throws this error.

In onchage method just set the value directly on the `self` record:

```
    student_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Etudiant', 
                                readonly=True, required=True,
                                default=45) 

    @api.onchange('projet_terminer_id')
    def choice_student(self):
        self.student_id = self.env['res.users'].sudo().browse(45)
```

From the look of you code I think you can keep the `onchange` if you want to reset the value of `student_id` whenever you change  `projet_terminer_id` field.

Comment: The return value of his method is `int` not `None`, just to clarify.